# Using the "less than" operator with dates

Tags: r, date, dataframe, if-statement

There is a dataframe consisting of three measures of dates (i.e. date1, date2, date3) and additional measures labelled "s1" and "s2". I am trying to create new columns labelled "x1" and "x2" based on these dates and the measures "s1" and "s2". For instance, column "x1" should take on value 3 if date1 is less than or equal to date2, otherwise it should keep the value of s1. Similarly, column "x2" should take on value 3 if date1 is less than or equal to date3, otherwise it should keep the value of s2. Below is a section of the data

```
df <-
structure(
list(
  id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,5L),
  date1 = c("1/4/2004", "3/8/2004", "NA", "13/10/2004","11/3/2003"),
  date2 = c("8/6/2002", "11/5/2004", "3/5/2004", 
"25/11/2004","21/1/2004"),
  s1=c(1,2,1,"NA","NA"),
  date3=c("23/6/2006", "24/12/2006", "18/2/2006", "NA","NA"),
  s2=c("NA","NA",2,"NA","NA")
 ),
.Names = c("id", "date1","date2","s1","date3","s2"),
 class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA,-5L),
 col_types = c("numeric", "date","date","numeric","date","numeric")
 )
```

I have tried the following code

```
df$x1<-ifelse(df$date1<=df$date2,3,s1)
df$x2<-ifelse(df$date1<=df$date3,3,s2)
```

It gives

```
  id      date1      date2 s1      date3 s2 x1 x2
1  1   1/4/2004   8/6/2002  1  23/6/2006 NA  3  3
2  2   3/8/2004  11/5/2004  2 24/12/2006 NA  2 NA
3  3         NA   3/5/2004  1  18/2/2006  2  1  2
4  4 13/10/2004 25/11/2004 NA         NA NA  3  3
5  5  11/3/2003  21/1/2004 NA         NA NA  3  3
```

From this, it appears "NA" in column"x2" does not respond to the code since "3/8/2004" is less than "24/12/2006" so I expect to have 3 in place of "NA" in column "x2". Could anyone clarify why this is happening and how it can be resolved. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date columns are of type character in the data.

```
class(df$date1)
#[1] "character"
```

We first need to convert them to Date object and then compare

```
cols <- paste0("date", 1:3)
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], as.Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
df$x1<-ifelse(df$date1 <= df$date2, 3, df$s1)
df$x2<-ifelse(df$date1 <= df$date3, 3, df$s2)

df
#  id      date1      date2 s1      date3 s2   x1 x2
#1  1 2004-04-01 2002-06-08  1 2006-06-23 NA    1  3
#2  2 2004-08-03 2004-05-11  2 2006-12-24 NA    2  3
#3  3       <NA> 2004-05-03  1 2006-02-18  2 <NA> NA
#4  4 2004-10-13 2004-11-25 NA       <NA> NA    3 NA
#5  5 2003-03-11 2004-01-21 NA       <NA> NA    3 NA
```

Or based on what output you need you can also use `dplyr` with `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("date")), as.Date, "%d/%m/%Y") %>%
  mutate(x1 = replace(s1, date1 <= date2, 3), 
         x2 = replace(s2, date1 <= date3, 3))
```